# Why are there people in Protestant countries with the last name "Pope"?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, papacy

The last name "Pope" is prevalent in places such as England and the USA. Are we to assume that all such people are Catholic? If not i.e. if they are Protestant, is this simply the result of lineage dating back to before the Reformation, or is there another reason entirely?

Answer (score 3):

According to
[Pope (disambiguation) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_(disambiguation)#People_named_Pope),

> Pope is a Scottish surname meaning father.

It has nothing to do with the Roman church.